# Saving attributes on a user fetched from a query (i.e. not on the currentUser)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am interested in saving attributes to users in the database based on actions that are performed by my `currentUser`.  Based on the following code, I get the error message "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp"

```
NSString *IDToFetch = @"some_id";
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"user_id" equalTo:IDToFetch];
PFUser *foundUser = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];

foundUser[@"new_column"] = @"Some text";
[foundUser saveEventually]; //here an exception is thrown
```

I was wondering if there is a work around to this where I could save attributes to the `foundUser` without having to log that user on.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've encountered the same problem but I can't recommend our work around. (create a new table for "other" user variables")

It's possible cloud code can touch the user objects, so that could be a work around, but I don't know.

Comment: @Pork I may be going this route as well.  Were there any issues that made this workaround not a good one?  I'd imagine besides the additional queries performed there shouldn't be any major issues..?  If you could share your experience with this it'd be great - thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to update a user that is not currently the logged in user you will need to call Parse using the `master-key`.

You can do this from CloudCode for example;

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId,
        newColText = request.params.newColText;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.set('new_col', newColText);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

and calling it from your iOS project;

```
[PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{
    @"userId": @"someuseridhere",
    @"newColText": @"new text!"
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @hank.  I am getting the error `Error: {"code":201,"message":"missing user password"} (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.11)`.  My users are all Facebook users, and I am unsure whether this is an issue related to it.

Comment: @hank any chance you could help me? I'm trying to use your solution but with a small change and having lots of trouble. Would really appreciate the help. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430652/adding-a-user-to-pfrelation-using-parse-cloud-code

Comment: 6 months later and I finally realized what a great answer this is.  Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what 'new_col' is ? Is that the object key or is newColText the object key ? Also do you have a swift version to call it?

Comment: Hi, I have used same function but not successful for me getting this error: "Parse.Cloud.define is not a function".

Comment: Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); has been deprecated in Parse Server version 2.3.0 (Dec 7, 2016).  From that version on, it is a no-op (it does nothing). You should now insert the   {useMasterKey:true}  optional parameter to each of the methods that need to override the ACL or CLP in your code.

Answer (score 2):

OK Providing this as an answer but basically not recommending it! I think the cloud code route is cleaner at the end of the day. But, this is arguably easier..

You can create another table that pairs with each user.

eg.

### table name

user_extra_details

### fields

User

Score

so other users can edit this particular field on user_extra_details

But as you suspect this can lead to lots of extra queries but it's not impossible, just... inconvenient. So here's how you'd access your data in that set up.

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithTable:@"Users"];
[userQuery whereKey:Some Key equalTo:some value];

PFQuery *userDetails [PFQuery queryWithTable:@"user_extra_details"];
[userDetails whereKey:@"User" inQuery:userQuery];
[userDetails includeKey:@"User"];
[userDetails fetch];
```

The thinng you have to be wry about is that duplicate details objects will create multiple results obviously. So I suggest doing a delete and insert vs doing an update of the extra_detail object to help combat any erroneous duplicates.

Comment: Really, you've stumbled on to the best approach.  It's much better to have a separate table like this.  And for sure, just as you say you must 'clean as you go'. It's totally normal to have to do this in the cloud. Looks great.