# How to update PFUser attribute from a non user?

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

I want to update my PFUser attribute that is called Rating. This rating attribute will get its data from a non user who post a rating score.However,I do not know how to get about this as Parse does not allow you to post data from a non user to a PFUser column for security reasons.I came across this post([Saving attributes on a user fetched from a query (i.e. not on the currentUser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649197/saving-attributes-on-a-user-fetched-from-a-query-i-e-not-on-the-currentuser))
And the question is a similar in concept but not in implementation. Here is what I have changed but I am not familiar with JavaScript so am currently struggling to implement the function using Cloud Code.

**Original function**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
var userId = request.params.userId,
    newColText = request.params.newColText;

var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

user.set('new_col', newColText);

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
});
});
```

**What I tried**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
var userId = request.params.userId,
    rating = request.params.rating;

var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

user.set('Rating', rating); //Is 'Rating' the PFUser field name?

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
});
});
```

**Calling function**

```
[PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{
    @"userId": @"someuseridhere",
    @"newColText": @"new text!"
}];
```

**My swift version**

```
private func didFinishTouchingCosmos(rating: Double)
{
    let query = PFUser.query()

    if let objectaidi = self.tutor?.objectId
    {
          query?.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectaidi, block: { (tutorobject, errar) in
            if let input = self.ratinginput
            {
               PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("editUser", withParameters: ["userId": objectaidi, "newColText": "new text!"])
                PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters: nil) {
                    (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    let responseString = response as? String
                    print(responseString)
                }
                print("AYYAYYAA")
            }
          })
    }       
}
```

The error that I get from my Javascript code :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in main.js:7

Please help!

Comment: im pretty sure you need to query the user first, you cant instanciate the user object just with its objectId, so in your cloud code, query the user, then set the new rating property on that object and then save it in the success block

Comment: Mind showing an example ? I am very weak in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! The answer is very simple :

**Calling function :**

```
private func didFinishTouchingCosmos(rating: Double)
{
    let query = PFUser.query()

    if let objectaidi = self.tutor?.objectId
    {
            query?.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectaidi, block: { (tutorobject, errar) in
            if let input = self.ratinginput
            {
                PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters: nil) {
                    (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    let responseString = response as? String
                    print(responseString)
                }
                PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("editUser", withParameters: ["userId": objectaidi, "rating": input.rating]) {
                    (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    let responseString = response as? String
                    print(responseString)
                }
                print("AYYAYYAA")

            }

          })
    }
```

And the Javascript code  is :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
               var userId = request.params.userId,
               rating = request.params.rating;

               var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
               user = new User({ objectId: userId });

               user.set('Rating', rating);

               Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
               user.save().then(function(user) {
                                response.success(user);
                                }, function(error) {
                                response.error(error)
                                });
               });
```